# map.size() not working with static map

Tags: java, spring-batch

Hey i am trying to get the size of Static map from other class...

i am defining Static map in one class...as

tasklet.class

```
  package com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;

import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.Subrogation;

import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.common.SubrogationConstants;

/**
 * @author Manan Shah
 * 
 */

public class SubrogationFileTransferTasklet implements Tasklet,
        InitializingBean {
    private Logger logger = LogManager
            .getLogger(SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.class);
    private Resource inputfile;
    private Resource outputfile;
    public static String fileLastName;

    public static String header = null;
    public static String trailer = null;
    public static List<Subrogation> fileDataListSubro = new ArrayList<Subrogation>();
    public List<String> fileDataListS = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static TreeMap<String, Subrogation> map = new TreeMap<String, Subrogation>();
    public int counter = 0;
    public String value;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(inputfile, "inputfile must be set");

    }

    public void setTrailer(String trailer) {
        this.trailer = trailer;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getTrailer() {
        return trailer;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public Resource getInputfile() {
        return inputfile;
    }

    public void setInputfile(Resource inputfile) {
        this.inputfile = inputfile;
    }

    public Resource getOutputfile() {
        return outputfile;
    }

    public void setOutputfile(Resource outputfile) {
        this.outputfile = outputfile;
    }

    public static void setFileDataListSubro(List<Subrogation> fileDataListSubro) {
        SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.fileDataListSubro = fileDataListSubro;
    }

    public static List<Subrogation> getFileDataListSubro() {
        return fileDataListSubro;
    }

    public static void setMap(TreeMap<String, Subrogation> map) {
        SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map = map;
    }

    public static TreeMap<String, Subrogation> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
            ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        value = (String) chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
                .getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("outputFile");

        readFromFile();

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    public void readFromFile() {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputfile.getFile()));
            fileLastName = inputfile.getFile().getName();
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (sCurrentLine.indexOf("TRAILER") != -1) {
                    setTrailer(sCurrentLine);
                } else if (sCurrentLine.indexOf("HEADER") != -1) {
                    setHeader(sCurrentLine);
                } else if (sCurrentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                } else {
                    fileDataListS.add(sCurrentLine);
                }

            }

            convertListOfStringToListOfSubrogaion(fileDataListS);
            writeDataToFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void convertListOfStringToListOfSubrogaion(List<String> list) {

        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Subrogation subrogration = new Subrogation();
            String s = iterator.next();
            subrogration.setGRP_NBR(StringUtils.substring(s, 0, 6));
            subrogration.setSECT_NBR(StringUtils.substring(s, 6, 10));
            subrogration.setAFP_VAL(StringUtils.substring(s, 10, 13));
            subrogration.setDOL_MIN_VAL(StringUtils.substring(s, 13, 20));
            subrogration
                    .setCORP_ENT_CD(StringUtils.substring(s, 20, s.length()));

            map.put(subrogration.getGRP_NBR() + subrogration.getSECT_NBR(),
                    subrogration);
            fileDataListSubro.add(subrogration);

        }

    }

    public void writeDataToFile() {
        try {

            File file = new File(value);

            if (!file.exists()) {

                logger.info("output file is:-" + file.getAbsolutePath());

                file.createNewFile();

            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry subrogation = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                // System.out.println(subrogation.getKey() + " = " +
                // subrogation.getValue());
                // it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

                bw.append(subrogation.getValue().toString()
                        + SubrogationConstants.filler58);

            }
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("subrogationFileTransferTasklet Step completes");

    }
}
```

In processor i want to put map size into int.

processor.class

```
   package com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.processor;



import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.Utils.SubrogationUtils;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.Subrogation;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.common.SubrogationConstants;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration.SubrogationFileTransferTasklet;

public class SubrogationProcessor implements
        ItemProcessor<Subrogation, Subrogation> {



    public SubrogationFileTransferTasklet fileTransferTasklet = new SubrogationFileTransferTasklet();

    SubrogationUtils subrogationUtils = new SubrogationUtils();

    public int countFromFile=SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.size();

    public static int totalRecords = 0;

    public static int duplicate = 0;

    @Override
    public Subrogation process(Subrogation subrogration) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (subrogationUtils.validateData(subrogration)) {
            Subrogation newSubro = new Subrogation();

            newSubro.setGRP_NBR(StringUtils.leftPad(subrogration.getGRP_NBR()
                    .trim(), SubrogationConstants.length6, "0"));

            if (subrogration.getSECT_NBR().trim().length() < 5) {
                newSubro.setSECT_NBR(StringUtils.leftPad(subrogration
                        .getSECT_NBR().trim(), SubrogationConstants.length4,
                        "0"));

            } else if (subrogration.getSECT_NBR().trim().length() == 5) {
                newSubro.setSECT_NBR(StringUtils.substring(subrogration.getSECT_NBR().trim(), 1));

            } else {
                return null;
            }

            newSubro.setAFP_VAL(StringUtils.leftPad(subrogration.getAFP_VAL()
                    .trim(), SubrogationConstants.length3, "0"));

            if (subrogration.getDOL_MIN_VAL().trim().contains(".")) {

                newSubro.setDOL_MIN_VAL(StringUtils.leftPad(StringUtils.substring(subrogration.getDOL_MIN_VAL(),0,subrogration.getDOL_MIN_VAL().indexOf(".")), SubrogationConstants.length7,
                        "0"));
            } else {
                newSubro.setDOL_MIN_VAL(StringUtils.leftPad(subrogration
                        .getDOL_MIN_VAL().trim(), SubrogationConstants.length7,
                        "0"));
            }

            newSubro.setCORP_ENT_CD(StringUtils.substring(
                    subrogration.getCORP_ENT_CD(), 0, 2));

            if (SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.containsKey(newSubro
                    .getGRP_NBR() + newSubro.getSECT_NBR())) {


                duplicate++;

                return null;
            } else {
                    if(SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.fileLastName.contains("TX")){
                        if(newSubro.getCORP_ENT_CD().equalsIgnoreCase("TX")){

                            SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.put(newSubro
                                    .getGRP_NBR() + newSubro.getSECT_NBR(), newSubro);
                        totalRecords++;
                        return newSubro;
                        }
                    }

                    else{
                        if(SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.fileLastName.contains("IL")){
                            if(!newSubro.getCORP_ENT_CD().equalsIgnoreCase("TX"))
                            {
                            newSubro.setCORP_ENT_CD("IL");
                            SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.put(newSubro
                                    .getGRP_NBR() + newSubro.getSECT_NBR(), newSubro);
                            totalRecords++;
                            return newSubro;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            return null;
                        }

                    }

                    return null;

            }

        }

        else {

            return null;
        }

    }


}

class SubrogrationException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8971030257905108630L;

    public SubrogrationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and at last i want to use that countFromFile in other class..

writer.class

```
  package com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.writer;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileFooterCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback;

import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.Utils.SubrogationUtils;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.Subrogation;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.common.SubrogationConstants;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration.SubrogationFileTransferTasklet;
import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.processor.SubrogationProcessor;

public class SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter implements FlatFileFooterCallback,FlatFileHeaderCallback{


    private Logger logger = LogManager
    .getLogger(SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter.class);

    SubrogationFileTransferTasklet fileTransferTasklet = new SubrogationFileTransferTasklet();

    SubrogationUtils subrogationUtils=new SubrogationUtils();

    SubrogationProcessor processor=new SubrogationProcessor();

    private ItemWriter<Subrogation> delegate;



    public void setDelegate(ItemWriter<Subrogation> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public ItemWriter<Subrogation> getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }




    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {

        //writer.write(SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.header);

    }

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {


        String trailer = SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.trailer;
        String s1 = StringUtils.substring(trailer, 0, 23);

        logger.info(" Data from input file size is---- "+new SubrogationProcessor().countFromFile);
        int trailerCounter=new SubrogationProcessor().countFromFile+SubrogationProcessor.totalRecords;
        logger.info(" Data comming from database is"+SubrogationProcessor.totalRecords);

        logger.info(" Duplicate data From DataBase is " +SubrogationProcessor.duplicate);

        logger.info(" Traileer is " + s1+ trailerCounter);

        writer.write(s1 + trailerCounter);


        SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.clear();
        SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.fileDataListSubro.clear();
        SubrogationProcessor.totalRecords=0;
        SubrogationProcessor.duplicate=0;

    }

    public void writeErrorDataToFile(List<String> errorDataList,String errorfile){
        File file;
        try {
            file = new File(errorfile);

            logger.info("error file is "+errorfile);   

                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);

                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                for(String data:errorDataList){

                bufferWritter.write(new Date()+" "+data);

                bufferWritter.write(SubrogationConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);
                }
                bufferWritter.close();
            }

        catch (IOException e) {

            throw new ItemStreamException("Could not convert resource to file: [" + errorfile + "]", e);
        }
    }
    /*
    public void write(List<? extends Subrogation> subrogation) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside writer");

        delegate.write(subrogation);

    }*/


}
```

so here in logger massage.size prints 0....
I am not able to understand why???

Comment: please post full code

Comment: It looks like the map is empty at the time you create `new SubrogationProcessor()`. Are you sure that the map shouldn't be empty at the time of the call?

Comment: map.put happens before countFromFile decleration? Remember: countFromFile will not contains the updated value, it will contains the size which the map has when it read the value

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes it works before the countFromFile..

Answer (score 1):

Do in this way to make sure that It is initialized with the current size of the map when object is constructed.

```
class SubrogationProcessor{

   public int countFromFile;

   public SubrogationProcessor(){
       countFromFile=SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.map.size();
   }
}
```

Comment: actually I increment  the map  in processor ...and i dont want the increment value of map
i want to use the same value which it has in tasklet class....

Comment: I don't know what are you doing. Store in some where else in static variable once set and access from there.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on when the "map.put" line of code is run. Is it in a static block in the tasklet class?

If processor instance is initialized before record has been added to the map then map.size() will indeed be 0.

my suggestion would be to add the map into a static block if at all possible or to debug the code and see when the .put() method is being called in comparison to when the .size() method is called

```
public static TreeMap<String, Subrogation> map = new TreeMap<String, Subrogation>();

static{
    map.put(subrogration.getGRP_NBR() + subrogration.getSECT_NBR(), subrogration);
}
```

Comment: map.put run first and it has values in it if we test that inside the process method... map.size() returns value....but countFromFile prints 0 in to the method also